# copy file to docker container from inside the running container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci

**Problem**:  How can I copy a file from the host to the container **from inside** the running container?

**TL;TR**:

**Idea**: I am using a gitlab server and I want to use Gitlab-ci in order to
1. test the commits
2. gather all the source files in a .tar
3. and finally deploy them to another server

**Current Status**: I have the previous 3 jobs defined in my .gitlab-ci.yml. 1 and 2 work just fine, but rsync throws a "Host key verification failed." error of course. Here is my "thinned out" version of my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: alpine

stages:
  - test
  - package
  - deploy

test:
  stage: test
  script: bla bla testing bla bla

package:
  stage: package
  script: tar -cvf source.tar htdocs    

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - apk update
  - apk add rsync openssh
  script:
   - rsync -vuar source.tar servadmin@123.123.123.123:/home/servadmin/transfer
```

I have no access to these containers other than this .yml file so I really need to find a way to copy the public key from the host to the container, but I have to do that from inside the container. Or I could use multi-runners etc etc but I am new to ci and I could avoid that for the moment

Comment: Did you try to create a custom image for gitlab runner with public key present?

Comment: Could you mount the key into the container as a volume? Being able to copy arbitrary files from the host into a container would be a huge security risk.

Comment: I used COPY instead of VOLUME. Would that be a security risk too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround inspired by the comments above and an example I found somewhere I can't recall:
1. Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine
COPY id_rsa /root/.ssh/
```

2. .gitlab-ci.yml (changes only for 'deploy' job):

.

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
    before_script:
      - apk update
      - apk add rsync openssh
      - mkdir -p /root/.ssh
      - eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
      - echo "    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config

      # install ssh-agent
      - 'which ssh-agent || ( apk update -y && apk add openssh-client -y )'

      # run ssh-agent
      - eval $(ssh-agent -s)

      #copy key to file
      - cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa ./key.file
      - chmod 600 ./key.file

      # add ssh key stored in SSH_PRIVATE_KEY variable to the agent store
      - ssh-add ./key.file

      # disable host key checking (NOTE: makes you susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks)
      # WARNING: use only in docker container, if you use it with shell you will overwrite your user's ssh config
      - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
      - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config'

      script:
       - rsync -arvvvce "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" source.tar servadmin@123.123.123.123:/home/servadmin/transfer
```

I guess `-arvvvce "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"` can be replaced with `-vuar` but not tested.